# Simple Question: Cocoa Unit Tests and MVC

Tags: cocoa, unit-testing, model-view-controller

I am new to unit testing, I understand the basic concepts, and I am able to get unit testing setup correctly in my Cocoa projects; however the thing that is giving me a hard time is what exactly I should be writing unit tests for. For example, I know that you should write tests for model objects, but is that all I should be writing tests for? Should I also be writing tests for controllers, and views? What exactly would I be testing then? Could somebody please try and clarify what you should write unit tests for and what I should be testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule I generally follow is that all public interface needs to be tested. It's always up to you what exactly to test however the bigger your test coverage the less possibility there is for some nasty bug to creep out.
BTW for testing views I suggest [Google Toolbox](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/) which allows you to compare screenshots.